# I am trying to get data using db with laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Actually, I was able to get the data with this method as I always do, but this time I get an error warning that is not an object.

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
$product= Product::all();
foreach($product as $pr){
    $vprice = DB::table('product_variation_prices')->where('product_id', '=', $pr->id)->where('is_xml', '=', 1)->first();
}
```

I want to get price and id fields from variation table above. Here is the method I used

```
dd(json_encode($vprice->id));

dump  the output i got with

{#2405 ▼
  +"id": 6812
  +"product_id": 16157
  +"option": "{"5155":{"id":6849,"variation_id":5155,"name":"Package"}}"
  +"price": "10.00"
  +"qyt": 0
  +"special_price": "50.00"
  +"is_available": 1
  +"is_xml": 1
}
```

Comment: `$pr` is not an object. What is `$pr` at that point in the code?

Comment: You try to access id on `$pr` variable, which is not an object as the error states.

Comment: $product= Product::all(); foreach($product as $pr){ .....

Answer (score 0):

$vprice is an array, you can acces to id using `$vprice['id']`

Or convert to object using
`$vprice = (object)DB::table('product_variation_prices')->where('product_id', '=', $pr->id)->where('is_xml', '=', 1)->first();`

If you have the model created for table product_variation_prices you can do some.

```
$vprice=ProductVariationPrices::where('product_id', '=', $pr->id)->where('is_xml', '=', 1)->first()
```

This option will return a object

Or even better, use a
[Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: $vprice['id'], Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: You have a $vprice for the query?

{{ $vprice?$vprice['id']:'not found' }}

Comment: yes, there are results when I type the sql query over navicat. But I don't understand why it's not happening here

Comment: I understand now. It gives an error when is_xml fields are 0. When they are all 1, the results come out. Shouldn't only 1s give the results?

Comment: It's depends of column type, is boolean, bit, numeric?, the column is nullable, there is a lot of options.

Comment: And laravel transform in some cases the query ->where('x',null') into ->whereNull('x') if the property is null, take care about that, maybe you expect a 0, and property is a null.